# MVC 5 Razor Navigation Active CLass

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to get the active class to show on my navigation.  I have written the htmlhelper:

```
public static string IsActive(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controller, string action)
    {
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

        var routeAction = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var routeController = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        var returnActive = (controller == routeController && action == routeAction);

        return returnActive ? "active" : "";
    }
```

and this is my navigation:

```
<li @Html.IsActive("MemberDashboard", "Index")><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "MemberDashboard")"><span class="fa fa-list-alt fa-lg fa-fw"></span> Accounts</a></li>
 <li @Html.IsActive("Transfer", "Index")><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Transfer")"><span class="fa fa-retweet fa-lg fa-fw"></span> Transfers</a></li>
```

The navigation doesn't go to active when I'm on said page.

Comment: What exactly is: this HtmlHelper htmlHelper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few things here that I can recommend:

1. You are outputting the result of `@Html.IsActive()` as an attribute on the `<li>` element. I think you'd want to assign this to the class atribute of the element.
2. I would compare controller and action strings using invariant culture and ignoring case to cover the likely strings you want to successfully match against.
3. I would return `null` from the method in the case the controller and action strings do not match the current controller and action. If `null` is returned and assigned to the class attribute of the `<li>` element, then the class attribute will not be outputted at all in the markup. Small difference, but perhaps a little cleaner than an empty class attribute.
4. I would match the order of controller and action in the method signature to the order they appear in framework methods. This will be more intuitive for others to use and less confusing in the long run.

So, applying all of the above

```
public static string IsActive(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string action, string controller)
{
    var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

    var routeAction = (string)routeData.Values["action"];
    var routeController = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];

    var isActive = string.Equals(controller, routeController, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                   && string.Equals(action, routeAction, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    return isActive ? "active" : null;
}
```

and usage

```
<li class="@(Html.IsActive("Index", "MemberDashboard"))">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "MemberDashboard")">
        <span class="fa fa-list-alt fa-lg fa-fw"></span> Accounts
    </a>
</li>
<li class="@(Html.IsActive("Index", "Transfer"))">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Transfer")">
        <span class="fa fa-retweet fa-lg fa-fw"></span> Transfers
    </a>
</li>
```

You may want to also include an `area` string too if you're planning on using areas.

Comment: What exactly is:  this HtmlHelper htmlHelper

Comment: @JoshYates1980 an extension method on HtmlHelper: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods